# which is the best method to use externel json file in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

which is the best method to use json file in ionic im very confused . The json file is working perfectly if i use local server (ionic serve). If i run the same app in android device (ionic run android) im getting file not found error .Someone please advice me how to use json in ionic and also post some sample code for the problem so that it will be easy to understand

Comment: Can you add the code of what you're trying to do?

Comment: $http.get('/groceryjson.json')
        .success(function(response) {
            $scope.mydata = response;
            $scope.booking = []; })

Comment: im trying to display the json data in table format